# How to execute a Greasemonkey script on every infinite scrolling event in a Twitter conversation?

Tags: javascript, twitter, greasemonkey

I'm trying to make a greasemonkey userscript that will work in Twitter conversations
(colorize names,usernames and each 1st @reply).

When a Twitter conversation has a lot of replies ([example link](https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/501392234299002880)),
then opening such a link displays only 3 screenfuls of replies(the initial screenful+2 more)
-at least in my 1920x1200 display-
and then you have to scroll down manually in order to see the rest of replies.

**How can I make my script executed on every infinite scrolling event 
(on every `Mousewheel down` or `PgDn` or `Down arrow ↓` keypress)?**

Someone has kindly suggested:

> Try inspecting the code in FF devtools debugger (right click the code
>   and choose 'prettify source') to see how `infiniteScrollWatcher` is
>   triggered

**So, I suppose that I should bind an event listener to this function using
[EventTarget.addEventListener](https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/501392234299002880), 
but I don't know how (this function is way too advanced for me)**.

The prettified source of that function is:

```
function infiniteScrollWatcher() {
  var a = 0,
  b = 1;
  this.checkScrollPosition = function () {
    var c = this.webkitFullscreenElement();
    if (c && this.node != c && !c.contains(this.node)) return;
    var d = this.$content.height(),
    e = !1;
    this.inTriggerRange(a) && (d > this.lastTriggeredHeight || this.lastTriggeredFrom(b)) ? (this.trigger('uiNearTheTop'), this.lastTriggerFrom = a, e = !0)  : this.inTriggerRange(b) && (d > this.lastTriggeredHeight || this.lastTriggeredFrom(a)) && (this.trigger('uiNearTheBottom'), this.lastTriggerFrom = b, e = !0),
    e && (this.lastTriggeredHeight = d)
  },
  this.inTriggerRange = function (c) {
    var d = this.$content.height(),
    e = this.$node.scrollTop(),
    f = e + this.$node.height(),
    g = Math.abs(Math.min(f - d, 0)),
    h = this.$node.height() / 2;
    return e < h && c == a || g < h && c == b
  },
  this.lastTriggeredFrom = function (a) {
    return this.lastTriggerFrom === a
  },
  this.resetScrollState = function () {
    this.lastTriggeredHeight = 0,
    this.lastTriggerFrom = - 1
  },
  this.webkitFullscreenElement = function () {
    return document.webkitFullscreenElement
  },
  this.after('initialize', function () {
    this.resetScrollState(),
    this.$content = this.attr.contentSelector ? this.select('contentSelector')  : $(document),
    this.on('scroll', utils.throttle(this.checkScrollPosition.bind(this), 100)),
    this.on('uiTimelineReset', this.resetScrollState),
    this.on('uiSwiftLoaded uiPageChanged', this.checkScrollPosition)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach:

Twitter sends via jQuery a request to get the results, the path will be:

```
/twitter.com/i/[username]/conversation/[conversationid]?[query]
```

jQuery includes the option to add a global success-handler to all ajax-requests, you may use this handler.

inside the handler:

1. parse the current url to get username and conversation-id
2. test the url of the AJAX-request against the path from above(replace username and conversation-id with the results from step#1)
3. check if the response contains a property `items_html` which includes non-whitespace-characters

When the steps #2 & #3 are successfull, new items have been loaded, execute your desired instructions.

Sample:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        twitter
// @namespace   twitter
// @include     https://twitter.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript== 

window.addEventListener('load', function() {

        var path=location.pathname.split(/\//,5),_url;

        //check if we're inside a conversation
        if(path.length>=4 && path[2]==='status' && !isNaN(path[3])){

          //create the path for the comparison
          _url='/'+['i',path[1],'conversation',path[3]].join('/')+'?';

          $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(a, b, opts, data) {
            if (opts.url.indexOf(_url) === 0 //urls match
                  &&
                data.items_html
                  &&
                data.items_html.match(/\S/)//new items availabe
            ) {
                //do what you want to
                alert('new content inserted');
            }
        });
        }

    },
    false);
```

But when you only want to apply a custom style you don't need to care about the new content, simply add a stylesheet with some custom rules to the document(may also be done via [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/stylish/)) :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        twitter
// @namespace   twitter
// @include     https://twitter.com/*
// @version     2
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var style=document.createElement('style');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
//name
style.sheet.insertRule('.tweet .stream-item-header strong.fullname' +
                       '{background:tomato;color:white}',0);
//username
style.sheet.insertRule('.tweet .stream-item-header span.username' +
                       '{background:tomato;color:black}',0);
//first @reply
style.sheet.insertRule('.tweet .tweet-text a.twitter-atreply:first-of-type *' +
                       '{background:blue;color:orange !important;}',0);
```